# How to find specific key:value 2 from python pymongo, MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, find, pymongo

My mongo db sample is:

MONGO

```
    > db.pages.findOne()

{
"_id" : ObjectId("519b6e81661b820d0e5d4f83"),
"papers" : {
    "text" : "RT @sydest: Sütaş reklamlarındaki inekleri erkekler seslendirdiği sürece bu cinsiyet ayrımcılığı bitmez...",
    "ID" : null,
    "paragraphs" : [
        {
        "text" : "RT @sydest: Sütaş reklamlarındaki inekleri erkekler seslendirdiği sürece bu cinsiyet ayrımcılığı bitmez...",
        "ID" : "0P107",
        "sentences" : [
            {
            "text" : "RT @sydest: Sütaş reklamlarındaki inekleri erkekler seslendirdiği sürece bu cinsiyet ayrımcılığı bitmez...",
            "ID" : "0S107",
            "words" : [
                {
                "text" : "RT",
                "ID" : "1W3"
                    },
                    {
                    "text" : "sydest",
                    "ID" : "5W11"
                    },
                    {
                    "text" : "Sütaş",
                    "ID" : "13W18"
                    },
                    {
                    "text" : "reklamlarındaki",
                    "ID" : "19W34"
                    },
                    {
                    "text" : "inekleri",
                    "ID" : "35W43"
                    },
                    {
                    "text" : "erkekler",
                    "ID" : "44W52"
                    },
                    {
                    "text" : "seslendirdiği",
                    "ID" : "53W66"
                    },
                    {
                    "text" : "sürece",
                    "ID" : "67W73"
                    },
                    {
                    "text" : "bu",
                    "ID" : "74W76"
                    },
                    {
                    "text" : "cinsiyet",
                    "ID" : "77W85"
                    },
                    {
                    "text" : "ayrımcılığı",
                    "ID" : "86W97"
                    },
                    {
                    "text" : "bitmez",
                    "ID" : "98W104"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
}
```

In this sample, i have one paper. In paper i have paragraphs key and as value sentences list. As same i have words key and as value words list in setences element.

I just want to get all "texts" which has "ID" with "W" letter. Shortly, i want to get all words in all document at once as a list or tuple. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's a more beautiful way to achieve what you want, but here's what I've came up to using `find()`.

MongoDB query:

```
db.so.find({'papers.paragraphs': {$elemMatch: {'sentences': {$elemMatch: {'words': {$elemMatch: {'ID': {$regex: 'W'}}}}}}}}, {'papers.paragraphs.sentences.words.text': 1}).pretty();
```

python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pymongo

mongo_db = pymongo.MongoClient().test

cursor = mongo_db.so.find({'papers.paragraphs':
                               {'$elemMatch':
                                    {'sentences':
                                         {'$elemMatch':
                                              {'words':
                                                   {'$elemMatch':
                                                        {'ID': {'$regex': 'W'}}}}}}}},
                          {'papers.paragraphs.sentences.words.text': 1})

results = []
for result in cursor:
    for paragraph in result['papers']['paragraphs']:
        for sentence in paragraph['sentences']:
            for word in sentence['words']:
                results.append(word['text'])

print results  # prints [u'RT', u'sydest', ... ]
```

Hope that helps.